# How to get the position of the screen in a picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have a problem to copy a picturebox at runtime that need the current position of the screen with respect to picturebox

In this line of code took the position of the picturebox but I need the position with respect to the screen. Is there any way we could do?

```
// gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(pictureBox1.Bounds.X, pictureBox1.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, pictureBox1.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

 if (saveScreenshot.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

       bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Bounds.Width, pictureBox1.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

       gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

       gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

       bmpScreenshot.Save(saveScreenshot.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);

    }
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but if you can figure out the scale ratio of the screenshot in the picture box you could probably come close to calculating the unscaled pointer position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the screen coordinates of a position of the picture box itself, use:

```
var screenPosition = form.PointToScreen(pictureBox1.Location);
```

To get the screen coordinates of a point within the picture box:

```
var screenPosition = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(new Point(10, 10));
```

That will give you the screen coordinates of the position (10, 10) within the picture box.

Comment: I have a problem my friend in this

var screenPosition = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(new Point(10, 10));

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'pictureBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I just need the current position with respect PictureBox1 on the screen if the user moves the form

Comment: I have solved my friend the problem is that using a timer but your answer is very useful. Greetings from Guadalajara Mexico =)